# How do i keep the number of rows based on the quantity of other column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been stuck figuring this out for a couple of days.

For example I have a dataframe below:

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
+---------+---------+
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartC   |       2 |
| PartC   |       2 |
| PartC   |       2 |
| PartC   |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

How do I turn the above dataframe into this:

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
+---------+---------+
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartA   |       4 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartB   |       3 |
| PartC   |       2 |
| PartC   |       2 |
+---------+---------+
```

As you can see I want to keep the number of rows based on the number on ColumnB

The closest solution that I found is using `df.groupby('ColumnA').tail(3)`
But i want the value in the tail to constantly changing based on the ColumnB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with select first value of `ColumnB` per group by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df = df.groupby('ColumnA').apply(lambda x: x.tail(x.ColumnB.iat[0])).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  ColumnA  ColumnB
0   PartA        4
1   PartA        4
2   PartA        4
3   PartA        4
4   PartB        3
5   PartB        3
6   PartB        3
7   PartC        2
8   PartC        2
```